# Sharepoint 2016 Custom List create "Direct Dial" column hyperlink

Tags: list, 2016, custom

I was wondering if anyone has step by step instructions with regards how to do the below. I have found a few things online but nothing worked yet.

SharePoint 2016 - An employee directory - custom list - I want to make phone numbers clickable on so that users can browse on their mobiles for a persons number and direct dial them by clicking on number on phone.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer this question myself! 
Just put in a hyperlink field in custom list and put **tel:** infront of the number it works a treat.

e.g. tel:010203004

Answer (score 0):

I just added the following JSON to the column's Column Formatting. This negates the need to remember to add the `tel:` in front of the number.

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "a",
   "txtContent": "@currentField",
   "attributes": {
      "target": "_blank",
      "href": "='tel:' + @currentField"
   }
}
```